# How to parse the timezone in this date string?

Tags: ios, nsdate

I would like to convert this string to NSDate: `"Sun, 08 Mar 2015 10:32:12 -0000"`

This is what I got working:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateformatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [dateformatter dateFromString:@"Sun, 08 Mar 2015 10:32:12"];
```

But I don't know how to parse the `-0000`, if its part of the string, the date would fail.

Comment: You don't have any specifier for the timezone in your date format. Add the right one - see the spec to know what it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a 'Z' to handle the timezone piece of the date string.

Example:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateformatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
NSDate *date = [dateformatter dateFromString:@"Sun, 08 Mar 2015 10:32:12 -0000"];
```